# How to define a default handler in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, request-mapping

How can I define a default handler, or controller action, that will be invoked when no other handler is found for a given URL?

I tried by using a catch-all pattern `/**` (syntax is Kotlin):

```
@Controller
class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    fun default(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this gets matched with **higher precedence that Spring's own handlers,** for example the static file path configured in `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` is no longer available. I need my default handler to have the lowest precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to add your implementation of `HandlerMapping` and add it to list of handlers. You need to specify the order of handlers taking care of request as well:

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping
      = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
    urlMap.put("/**", defaultController());
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(1);
    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}
```

Here the `defaultController()` method returns a `@Controller`, that you have defined for the given mapping, so `DefaultController`. The `setOrder` method defines a priority (order) of handlers, starting from 0. Of course some default `HandlerMapping` must be defined as a `@Bean` as well. More about such configuration you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-handler-mappings).

Edit with some thoughts from @Tobia:

You need to remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation so that the controller is not picked up by `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and implement the `AbstractController` interface to override the definition of controller in `handleRequestInternal()`.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure it works. I used `setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` instead of 1, but it still overrides the resource handler. I need it to be considered *after* the resource handler.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot, so there are several default handlers. I just need to add mine. I have inspected the application beans (using `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(HandlerMapping.class)` and I can see that mine is loaded with order=2147483647, which is a higher number (lower precedence) than order=2147483646 resourceHandlerMapping. That one is the default SimpleUrlHandlerMapping for static files, with a clear urlMap of `/static/**`. But whenever I call a static URL, my controller is invoked instead.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. My controller is still being picked up by requestMappingHandlerMapping because it still has the @RequestMapping annotation. But if I remove the annotation, I get `javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [...Controller@6da127ce]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler`

Comment: So I had to remove @RequestMapping, implement AbstractController and override `handleRequestInternal()` "the old way" (Spring and Spring Boot have different definitions of what is a "Controller"...) Now it works. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Damn, that is quite a good job. Honestly, I have never implemented it myself, I didn't know there is that much to it.

Comment: No problem. I've learn a bit myself. I've edited the answer with your information, so that it's complete.