# error navigating to unmapped urls after setting a default hander

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 6.0.11, Java 19. I set a defaultHandler in the java based config file like so

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
    
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();

    ErrorController ec = new ErrorController();
    handlerMapping.setDefaultHandler("errorController");
    return handlerMapping;  
}
```

ErrorController is:

```
package com.sp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/error")
public class ErrorController{
    
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping
    public String error() {
        
        System.out.println("test test test");
        return "test test test";
    }
}
```

When I navigate to an unmapped webpage to be handled by the ErrorController, I get the following error:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.sp.controllers.ErrorController@14a028ca]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

I tried to set the defaultHandler using RequestMappingHandlerMapping.setDefaultHandler(). I was expecting the message I return from ErrorController.error() to be shown anytime I hit a url in my web app without an explicit mapping, but instead I get the error message.

Comment: Can you try `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: I tried @RestController, it works for the /error url as before, but any non mapped url throws the same error

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840822/how-to-define-a-default-handler-in-spring-boot-2

Comment: I guess that would work, but I'm trying to understand Spring. The way I did it ErrorController is already a handler when used the normal way. Why does the error message say there is no adapter for ErrorController when there must be as when I navigate to the actual url, it returns the correct view with no error? What is different about setting defaultHandler through RequestMappingHandlerMapping? Seems like it would be straightforward...

Comment: After a lot more research I found what is probably the best answer I can get without really digging into mvc source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15203. Its from a long time ago, but I'm just assuming it still holds. According to the resolution to the issue, annotated controllers cannot be set as defaultHandler as of Spring 3.1  Thus, I implemented the ErrorController as org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller, using no annotations, this allows the defaultHandler to work correctly when set. :)